Безопасность запросов Django
Пишу программу на питоне, есть защита по HWID. При обнаружении в базе данных HWID "none", он отправляет GET запрос на django сервер с аргументами логин-HWID. Каждый кто декомпилирует прогу сможет изменить себе HWID на "none", то есть сбросить его, а эта услуга должна быть платной. Есть способ это исправить?
        try:
            params_auth = {'login': self.login.text(), 'pass': self.password.text()}
            response_auth = requests.get('http://212.60.5.252/', params=params_auth, timeout=10)
            params_get_hwid = {'login': self.login.text()}
            response_get_hwid = requests.get('http://212.60.5.252/get_hwid/', params=params_get_hwid, timeout=10)
            if response_auth.text.strip().lower() == "true":
                if response_get_hwid.text.strip().lower() == "none":
                    hwid = get_machine_guid()
                    params_set_hwid = {'login': self.login.text(), 'hwid': hwid}
                    requests.get('http://212.60.5.252/set_hwid/', params_set_hwid, timeout=10)
                    download_and_run_jar(jar_url)
                elif response_get_hwid.text.strip().lower() == "admin":
                    download_and_run_jar(jar_url)
                else:
                    if response_get_hwid.text.strip().lower() == hwid:
                        download_and_run_jar(jar_url)
                    else:
                        self.incorrect_label.setText("HWID не совпадает!")
                        self.incorrect_label.setStyleSheet("color: red")
                        self.wait_lable.setStyleSheet("color: transparent")

P.S. Речь идет о requests.get('http://212.60.5.252/set_hwid/'

Для этого даже декомпилировать не надо, достаточно просто трафик прослушать

в этом и смысл, как это исправить?

Никак, сделать защиту принципиально невозможно
